$\mathbb R^n$ version of proof that uniform continuity implies boundedness
I have seen a lot of questions on the site about the proof that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on an interval, then its range is bounded. However, I have not been able to find a question that addresses the multi-dimensional version of the proof. I am currently trying to prove the following:

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbf f:E\to\mathbb R^m$. Suppose $\mathbf f$ is uniformly continuous and $E$ is bounded. Then $\mathbf f(E)$ is bounded.

This is my attempt:
Since $E$ is bounded there is an $M>0$ such that $B(\mathbf 0,M)\supseteq E$. Let us consider the closure of this ball. It is closed and bounded, so it has the Heine–Borel property. Let $\epsilon>0$. We then have a $\delta>0$ such that for
all $\mathbf x,\mathbf y \in E$, $\lVert\mathbf x-\mathbf y\rVert<\delta\implies\lVert\mathbf f(\mathbf x)-\mathbf f(\mathbf y)\rVert<\epsilon.$ Let us form a $\delta$-ball around each point in $\overline B(\mathbf 0,M)$. These balls form an open cover for $\overline B(\mathbf 0, M)$, so compactness lets us pick a finite number of them that will cover $\overline B(\mathbf 0, M)$. Let us call the centers of these balls $\mathbf z_k$, $k=1,...,j$.
Any $\mathbf x \in E$ is less than $\delta$ away from some $\mathbf z_k$, and assuming for all $k\le j$, $\mathbf f (\mathbf z_k)$ exists, then $\mathbf f(\mathbf x)$ will be less than $\epsilon$ away from $\mathbf f (\mathbf z_k)$. We have only finitely many $\mathbf f(\mathbf z_k)$, so we can choose the one with maximum norm, and then add $\epsilon$ to it. All $\mathbf f(\mathbf x)$ will have a norm less than this number, so $\mathbf f (E)$ is bounded.
However, there is no guarantee that all $\mathbf z_k$ lie within $E$. If the whole $\delta$-ball around $\mathbf z_k$ does not even lie in $E$, then we can forget about it, but it is possible that some part of the ball does lie in $E$, yet $\mathbf z_k$ does not and so $\mathbf f (\mathbf z_k)$ does not exist.
How do I get around this issue? Is my approach completely wrong?
Any hints or answers would be greatly appreciated.

How about: $E\subseteq B=\overline{B}(0, M)$ (the closed ball), so that $f(E)\subseteq f(B)$. But $B$ is compact (Heine-Borel), so that $f(B)$ is also compact (as $f$ is continuous). Thus by Heine-Borel $f(B)$ is closed and bounded, so in particular $f(E)$ is bounded. I don't see why uniform continuity is needed?

@GhostAmarth This suffers from the same issue as OP's proof, namely that $f$ is not necessarily defined on $B$.

@AnneBauval I knew I was missing something extremely simple. Thank you. That solves it.

@user1149748 oh yes sure i didn't read the statement thoroughly enough; my bad. sorry.
